# Spring Cloud Sleuth with RabbitTemplate

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a problem with spring cloud sleuth and rabbitTemplate. When i send post with my service and pulibsh message on rabbitmq using rabbitTemplate, my second service consume the message, but not respect same trace id generate on service 1. Exists any soluction for hold on the same trace?

Comment: Have you injected the template as a bean?

Comment: Sorry for not response. Yes, i'm injecting, but the spring sleuth not working with '@RabbitListener' annotation, only '@StreamListener'. I'm make override the default operation and considerate my trace. =)

Comment: All the configs needed to achieve traceId propagation are here: https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/tree/master/instrumentation/spring-rabbit

Comment: I had this problem and solved with using simple listener instead of direct. So if anyones uses `spring.rabbitmq.listener.type=direct` I recommend to try replacing it with simple (assuming you direct listener is not a MUST for you). I did not even need to add the configs @KonstantinZyubin shared